# Swift: Set UIButton background color to colorWithAlphaComponent for highlighted state

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to set the background color of a custom `MyButton` UIButton to the button's current background color with an alpha component for a highlighted state. Similarly to how a UIButton's text title dims/darkens when the button is in a highlighted state.

I have been trying to achieve this for days, and ultimately came up with this line of code that seems to make the most sense, however, does not work:
`self.setBackgroundColor((self.backgroundColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5))!, forState: .Highlighted)`

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class MyButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.setBackgroundColor((self.backgroundColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5))!, forState: .Highlighted)

    }

}

extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forState: forState)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us what is the result of your modification ?

Comment: @DamienBallenghien The result is that my button looks the same in its normal and highlighted state. (See update above for screenshot)

Comment: It is strange because it works well for me ... Did you set anything else for your button ? In the storyboard/Xib for example ?

Comment: @DamienBallenghien Besides the code above, I just added a `UIButton` to the storyboard and changed it's class to `MyButton` in the Identity Inspector. What did you do to make it work?

Comment: @DamienBallenghien I lowered the the Alpha of the background color of my button in the storyboard and strangely it works. However, I don't want to the initial background color of the button to have any other alpha other than 1.0